# Running into a bit of a conundrum with my program (note can not use ArrayList)

Tags: java, arrays

my program consists of a String Array with a size of 25. What I'm attempting to do is create an add method that adds elements to this array  When I attempt to add the same string, I create a method that displays the number of times that particular item is listed within the String array (I use a hash map to do this). The program is not working as planned. There seems to be something off about my add method because when I add a new element, instead of incrementing to the next index in the array, it restarts at index 0 (which makes sense since each time you call the add method i = 0). What can I do in order to modify this method to go to the next index if something is added? Thanks, please see code below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment1 {




        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Assignment1 ();
        }

        // This will act as our program switchboard
        public Assignment1 (){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] flowerPack = new String[25];
            int[] flowerCount = new int[25];
            System.out.println("Welcome to my flower pack interface.");
            System.out.println("Please select a number from the options below");
            System.out.println("");

            while(true){
                // Give the user a list of their options
                System.out.println("1: Add an item to the pack.");
                System.out.println("2: Remove an item from the pack.");
                System.out.println("3: Sort the contents of the pack.");
                System.out.println("4: Search for a flower.");
                System.out.println("5: Display the flowers in the pack.");
                System.out.println("0: Exit the flower pack interfact.");

                // Get the user input
                int userChoice = input.nextInt();

                switch(userChoice){
                    case 1: 
                        addFlower(flowerPack);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        removeFlower(flowerPack);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        sortFlowers(flowerPack);
                        break;
                    case 4: 
                        searchFlowers(flowerPack);
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        displayFlowers(flowerPack);
                        break;
                    case 0: 
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using the flower pack interface. See you again soon!");
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }

        }

        private void addFlower(String flowerPack[]) {
            // TODO: Add a flower that is specified by the user
            int i = 0;

            String flowerName;
            Scanner flowerInput = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a flower type to add:");
            flowerName = flowerInput.nextLine();
            flowerPack[i] = flowerName;
            i++;

        }

        private void removeFlower(String flowerPack[]) {
            // TODO: Remove a flower that is specified by the user
            String flowerName;
            Scanner flowerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a flower type to remove");
            flowerName = flowerInput.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length; i++) {
                if (flowerPack[i].equals(flowerName)) {
                    flowerPack[i] = ""; //Will ask professor if we should set to NULL instead
                }
            }
        }

        private void sortFlowers(String flowerPack[]) {
            // TODO: Sort the flowers in the pack (No need to display them here) - Use Selection or Insertion sorts
            // NOTE: Special care is needed when dealing with strings! research the compareTo() method with strings

            Arrays.sort(flowerPack);
        }

        private void searchFlowers(String flowerPack[]) {
            // TODO: Search for a user specified flower
            String flowerType;
            Scanner flowerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a flower to search for:");
            flowerType = flowerInput.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < flowerPack.length; i++) { //done in O(n) time This is a linear search
                if (flowerPack[i].equals(flowerType)) {
                    System.out.println("Found your flower " + flowerPack[i]);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid flower type!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void displayFlowers(String flowerPack[]) {
            // TODO: Display only the unique flowers along with a count of any duplicates
            /*
             * For example it should say
             * Roses - 7
             * Daffodils - 3
             * Violets - 5
             */

            Map<String,Integer> theFlowers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            for(int i=0;i<flowerPack.length;i++){

                if(theFlowers.get(flowerPack[i])==null){
                    theFlowers.put(flowerPack[i],1);
                }else{
                    theFlowers.put(flowerPack[i], theFlowers.get(flowerPack[i])+1);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(theFlowers);

        }



}
```

Comment: Code review item: you don't need so many `Scanner` objects. You could just use a single instance and share it among all your methods since all of them are reading from `System.in`.

Comment: LOL true, it is a bit redundant. Thanks for the code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to add at max 25 flowers and then stop, or do you want to override the first String when a 26th flower is added?

If you only want to add at max 25 flowers the easiest approach would be to add the new String at the first position with an empty String inside the array.
Something like

```
flowerName = flowerInput.nextLine();
for(int i=0; i<flowerPack.length; i++){
    if(flowerPack[i] == null || flowerPack[i].equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        flowerPack[i] = flowerName;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to rotate on the array (after the 25th flower is added you overwrite the first array element), you have to remember the next Index to add a flowername. 
The index could be a class variable (but you shoudn't call it 'i' if you want to use a class variable, since 'i' is often used in loops)

Edit: Added flowerPack[i] != null

(The code is untested and most likely still contains errors)

Edit 2: Added a break so the flower name is only saved at one position inside the array.

Comment: The problem though is that I am using a switch-case structure here. I want to be able to add an item then go back to the switch case and make another choice and have the option of coming back to add something else again. With the for loop, it will just keep looping until we reach the final element right?

Comment: @Linuxn00b The for-loop should be inside the add method, so after running it you return to your switch case structure. Also you are right, that the loop kept looping until it reached the final element and the loop overwrit every null/empty position in the array (instead of only one position) (I just fixed that). Normally the loop should run over every element in the array, look if the element is empty and if it is empty, add the new flower. The 'problem' with this code is, that you can only add 25 flowers and after that you have to remove one before adding a new one

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try

Answer (score 0):

You should find out how many items are in the array.  Use that number to see what index to use.

Comment: Arrays don't have a .size() method, they have a .length attribut. Also the arraylength is set to 25, so flowerPack.length would always return 25.

Comment: Looks like you are right, so, without the .size() method available you'll have to discover yourself how many elements are being used in the array.  One way to do that would be to have another variable in your class that gets incremented each time you add an element.  You can then use your variable to know what the next element would be.

Comment: Then in your remove method you would decrement the variable when a flower is removed from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issue - inside your `addFlower(...)` method you have `int i = 0;` which creates a new local variable every time the method is invoked and sets its value to 0. In other words your `i++` in this method is meaningless because the variable is local to the method and resets every time you call the method. See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for details about variables.

I agree with the answer by "Mein Name" in that the simplest way to add items would be to find the first position you consider to be empty/invalid and place your new item in that position.

Remember if you do decide to keep track of the current number of items in the array using a class member variable then you will want to decrement that variable when you remove items.